# Splitting string in java

Tags: java, string, split

I have input as follows

```
Date    Place  total trains
monday,chennai,10
tuesday,kolkata,20
wednesday,banglore,karnataka,30
```

I want to split this data.So far I have used

```
String[] data = input.split(",");
```

If I do like above I am getting

```
index[0]  index[1]                  index[2]
monday     chennai                    10
tuesday     kolkata                   20
wednesday   banglore                 karnataka          30
```

But I want the output like below

```
index[0]     index[1]                    index[3]
wednesday     banglore,karnataka          30
```

Is there any way to achieve this

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind your expected result?

Comment: The number of items in your rows don't match the number of columns you have in the CSV format. You should modify your input to separate items in the same column with any separator other than ','.

Comment: Why would you want "banglore,karnataka" at index[1]?

Comment: @Upio - Well because its like - `Mountain View, CA`. city, state combination

Comment: @TheLostMind Oh i see. You need to store it in the proper CSV format that uses quotes around strings that contain ','. And then use (or implement) a CSV parser that handles quoted records.

Comment: @Upio - *ideally* yes. But if the Op is *getting these values* from a service, then he hardly has control over this :P

Comment: @TheLostMind Hmmm it must be a pretty bad service to do that. But you are technically correct :P

Answer (score 0):

Split your input according to the first comma or the last comma.

```
String s = "wednesday,banglore,karnataka,30";
String parts[] = s.split("(?<=^[^,]*),|,(?=[^,]*$)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Output:

```
[wednesday, banglore,karnataka, 30]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you split a string with a regex, you essentially tell where the string should be cut. This necessarily cuts away what you match with the regex. Which means if you split at `\w`, then every character is a split point and the substrings between them (all empty) are returned. Java automatically removes trailing empty strings, as described in the documentation.

This also explains why the lazy match `\w*?` will give you every character, because it will match every position between (and before and after) any character (zero-width). What's left are the characters of the string themselves
Try
`String[] data = input.split("(?<=^\\w+),|,(?=\\d+)");`

Some good Explanations is [here](http://www.acrobatfaq.com/atbref5/index/ActionsRules/Operators/FullOperatorList/Stringsplitpattern.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sticking to the basics, your data has to be in this format.

```
Date,Place,total trains
"monday","chennai","10"
"tuesday","kolkata","20"
"wednesday",'banglore,karnataka","30"
```

Because, if both delimiter and data are same, then either write a complex code to handle to simply put your data in double quotes. csv files also uses this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the position of "," you can get rid of it.

Program below replaces 2nd instance of , with " " so string.split() works as needed

need to  import import java.util.regex.*;

===========

```
public static void main(String args[]){

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
String s = "wednesday,banglore,karnataka,30";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(",");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
int count = 1;
while(m.find()) {
      if(count == 2 ){

        m.appendReplacement(sb, " ");
    }
    count++;

}
m.appendTail(sb);

System.out.println(sb);

s= sb.toString();
String[] data = s.split(",");

System.out.println( data[0] + "-" + data[1] + "-" +data[2] );


    }//psvm
```

## Output

wednesday,banglore karnataka,30
wednesday-banglore karnataka-30

Answer (score -1):

This code will work for you :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s1 = "wednesday,banglore,karnataka,30";
    String s2 = "monday,chennai,10";
    String[] arr1 = s1.split("(?<=^\\w+),|,(?=\\d+)");
    for(String ss : arr1)
        System.out.println(ss);
    System.out.println();
    String[] arr2 = s2.split("(?<=^\\w+),|,(?=\\d+)");
    for(String ss : arr2)
        System.out.println(ss);
}
```

O/P :

```
wednesday
banglore,karnataka
30

monday
chennai
10
```

Comment: @SergeyPauk - This is a *special case* how can you expect a *generic* answer to a *non-generic* question?

Comment: @SergeyPauk - My code does that. It works as expected for `"wednesday,banglore,karnataka,India,Asia,30"` --> arr[1]===>`banglore,karnataka,India,Asia`

Comment: @SergeyPauk - I would do it if it is valid (even if you *downvote*) :P